# Difficulty in maintaining x[i,i] in a for loop

Tags: r

I've been having a problem in

```
sum <- (abs(x[i, i] - x[i, j])^p) ^ (1/p)
```

I want it to be for example `x[1,1]` ,`x[2,2]` etc. So I thought `x[i,i]` in the for loop would do the job, but it's only giving me back 0 as a result.

```
example <- function (x,p) {

sum <- 0

for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {

  for (j in i:nrow(x)){

    sum<-(abs(x[i,i] - x[i,j])^p) ^ (1/p)

  }

}

  return (sum)

}

 #x is a matrix
```

Comment: Please take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your text is unreadable because of wrong formating.

Comment: Please always look at your post in the review section. Show that you have put a minimal effort into getting your question answered. If you do, people will be willing to put in some effort into helping you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even though you got an answer you should still [edit] your question to improve the formatting and include a [mcve]. This will help you getting answers when your questions aren't as trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing sum each time you loop through, 
`sum <- sum + (abs(x[i,i] - x[i,j])^p) ^ (1/p)`  should do.

Comment: You can thank me , by accepting the answer, if the answer was helpful !

Comment: first time posting so i had a little bit to see how it works .thanks again !